# how to receive @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM) into java rest(jersey)?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jersey-2.0

```
@Path("/upload/")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response uploadAttachment(@QueryParam("fileName") String fileName
         ) {}
```

i am sending file from form-data in post. [here is image file format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrWJU.jpg). but unable to retrieve this file into this  method. can someone help me.

Comment: There is a jersey tutorial for file uploads here https://howtodoinjava.com/jersey/jersey-file-upload-example/

Comment: i am using jersey not spring

Comment: Sorry, updated link in the comment

Answer (score 0):

You have to use @FormDataParam and not @QueryParam.
So it would look like:

```
@Path("/upload/")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response uploadAttachment(@FormDataParam("fileName") String fileName) {}
```

Doc: http://javadox.com/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-multipart/2.17/org/glassfish/jersey/media/multipart/FormDataParam.html